# how to generate id for images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
function displayImage(whichImage) {
    if (whichImage !== "noImage") {
        document.canvas.src = whichImage;
    } else {
        document.canvas.src = "image2.jpg";
    }
}
```

I am using this code but i want that for every image fetched from database should have unique id. so is there any code in javascript?

Comment: this image is fetched from database.. there can be any number of images..

Comment: an incremented counter might do the trick. (handle a map with a simple indexOf internally).

Comment: Off-topic: you can simplify your code to `document.canvas.src = whichImage !== "noImage" ? whichImage : "image2.jpg"`

Comment: If you're fetching an image from the database, could you assign the ID number of the image as an ID?

Comment: yes exactly that is my question.. is there any trick in javascript through which i can assign id to the images fetched from the database?

Comment: you know how to fetch the image path from database but not the ID... no comment...

Comment: @nIlAmnAgHoR I don't believe that you can directly get the ID of the image through javascript (since its client-side and all) but I'm sure you can do something with PHP.  Or, perhaps, you can just devise something that assigns an ID based on the name of the image file.  Populus, it is possible that he/she may be working with another dev or followed a specific tutorial if they aren't familiar with MySQL - or is asking for a less-hassle way.

Comment: @oriol That's not simplifying, it's complicating the syntax but making it shorter...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you just want a unique id on the client side and not to be used as a mechanism of consistency between front/backend. Like, everytime the page loads, these ids' must be the same. My addition is just for client side uniqueness.

```
function displayImage(whichImage) {
    if (whichImage !== "noImage") {
        document.canvas.src = whichImage;
    } else {
        // you can increment via document.images or just randomize a numb.
        var docimages = document.images.length || Math.floor(Math.random()*999999);
        document.canvas.src = "image2.jpg";
        document.canvas.id = 'image' + docimages;
    }
}
```

If you want to absolutely have a unique id (which is good), and don't want to take the chance of docimages not giving you something unique. Create a hash, and callback function to test to see if you've generated the id, if not - randomize it and add it. If you do, re-randomize and check again. Or just test against the ID in the document if it has a length before you assign it. If not, add it to the id -- if it exists, re-rerandomize.

Comment: This certainly gives a random ID, but will it not be generated every time the page loads?  That could be a problem depending on OP's needs.  E.g. simple CMS systems like pagelime require unique ID's that stay the same.

Comment: true, I assume that func is part of some looping mechanism so the docimages is updated everytime it is called. And yeah, I was working on another assumption that is was just for client side usage. My assumptions could be wrong though :-(

Comment: Still, +1 because you answered OP's question with the given info.

Comment: yes every time when image is fetched from database and when clicked on image this function is called so i want unique id for that images..

Comment: @nIlAmnAgHoR if you are fetching from the database, why are you not just using the row's ID?